# How can I use virtual member functions in multi-file programs?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

So I just figured out that it was much simpler to just use multiple files to separate classes from each other and keep things nice and tidy, instead of dealing with 10 000 line programs inside the one file. Unfortunately this has caused some issues with the virtual member functions I was using in the computer program I was "partitioning". 
My working directory looks like this:

```
main.cpp (the main function and other ambiguous stuff)
foo.h (declaration an object, including prototype of virtual function "baz")
foo.cpp (implementation of the above object object, including implementation of virtual function "baz")
bar.h (declaration of an object that inherits from foo (includes "foo.h"))
bar.cpp (implementation of the bar object, including a redefinition of the "baz" object)
```

The only issue I am having is an error when I implement the baz objct in foo.cpp. the error is "E0239: invalid specifier outside a class declaration".
I can't figure out why I can't implement the baz function outside the object (in the .cpp file). It seems to want me to declare it and implement it in foo.h, which kinda counteracts the idea of separating the source in the first place.

I get the feeling I'm doing something very wrong, but I don't know what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post the code that caused the error too. The error itself is not enough context.

Comment: Try removing the virtual keyword/specifier from the virtual function definition in the cpp file. You only need it in the header file.

Comment: Thanks @AmouroK , not getting the error!

Comment: You will get the same error if you write the definition inside the header but outside the class definition. It is not caused by having multiple files.